# Table importation fails with error code ORA-31693

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, impdp, expdp

I've been receiving backups from an Oracle database into my Oracle database for 2 years now. My company is running version 10.2.0.1.0 and we are receiving the exports from version 12.1.0.2.0. They are using expdp and I'm using impdp. I added a new column into my database, using this script

```
ALTER TABLE CONTAINERS 
ADD ("SHELL" NUMBER(14, 6) DEFAULT 0 );
```

After running the above on both databases now when they send an export to me the table in question will not import. I receive the following error.

```
ORA-31693: Table data object "PAS"."CONTAINERS" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-02373: Error parsing insert statement for table "PAS"."CONTAINERS".
ORA-00904: "SYS_NC00067$": invalid identifier
```

This error has been going on for a about two weeks, I have tried to resolve the problem multiple ways, this is my last resort as it were.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to track down SYS_NC00067? It looks like a system-assigned column name. This sometimes happens when you add a function-based index. Did you create a function-based index on Shell?

Comment: Good question, I did, that column doesn't exist in my database, I'm checking with the DBA on the other side to see if they have the column. I didn't create a function based index on shell. As a matter of fact shell isn't an index or key to anything. I'll add that tidbit to my main question. and get back with you on the column in the other database.

Comment: Ok you got me there. There is a function for this table that uses the new column. Of course I updated this function alongside the column. It never occurred to me that this could be helping the problem I'm having. I just reviewed the code for the function and actually found a very minor typo. I have informed the DBA on the other side and am getting another data set sent to me, we'll see if that does anything.

Comment: Ugh... this may be a problem, since I believe function-based virtual columns were introduced in Oracle 11. So "their" db supports them but yours doesn't. Good luck!